# WordPress wp-admin login problem

Tags: wp-admin

I want to log into wp admin, but I am getting an unfamiliar login form. Is it normal? Image below.[image]

Comment: That's an HTTP Basic Authentication form. WordPress doesn't use it, but it's something a server could put in front of a WordPress install. I suggest contacting your host about it. I would *not* attempt to put any details into it until talking to your host, just in case the site's been compromised and someone else is receiving them.

Comment: is this form from your theme? don't enter login info till you're sure.

Comment: Most probably site is hacked. Otherwise check plugins through cpanel or terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it's normal. If your user and password not working. Then You need to put default user id and password
User: admin
Password: admin
or 
User: Human
password: admin
after then you need to use your original user id and password.